# Objective-C: weird ternary behavior

Tags: objective-c, ternary-operator

I have a simple function that returns a primitive sum of `NSNumber`s, but doesn't count them if they're -1:

```
- (NSInteger)total {
    return [[self obj1] integerValue] == -1 ? 0 : [[self obj1] integerValue] + 
           [[self obj2] integerValue] == -1 ? 0 : [[self obj2] integerValue] +
           [[self obj3] integerValue] == -1 ? 0 : [[self obj3] integerValue];
}
```

In this case `total` will always return 0.

But if I write it like this:

```
- (NSInteger)total {
    NSInteger ret = 0;
    ret += [[self obj1] integerValue] == -1 ? 0 : [[self obj1] integerValue];
    ret += [[self obj2] integerValue] == -1 ? 0 : [[self obj2] integerValue];
    ret += [[self obj3] integerValue] == -1 ? 0 : [[self obj3] integerValue];
    return ret;
}
```

`total` will return the correct value.

I don't have a preference for writing it one way over the other, but I don't see what's wrong with the first way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that happens because `+` is executed before `?:`, just like `5+4*3` is 17 and not 27

Comment: Btw, you ***should*** be using an array of `NSNumber`s and a `for()` loop for this.

Comment: `[self obj1]` was a simplification, some of the NSNumbers are methods while others are straight from Core Data. I figured the distinction would just confuse my question. Properties vs methods are blurry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator precedence. The ternary operator has the third lowest precedence in C, so the addition is evaluated before it could get to the conditional part. Use parentheses:

```
return ([[self obj1] integerValue] == -1 ? 0 : [[self obj1] integerValue]) + 
       ([[self obj2] integerValue] == -1 ? 0 : [[self obj2] integerValue]) +
       ([[self obj3] integerValue] == -1 ? 0 : [[self obj3] integerValue]);
```